# Spring MVC CSS/JS not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my maven Spring Project in netbeans  CSS/Js file not opening ..
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>OrderManager</display-name>     
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfiguration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfiguration</servlet-name>     
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

SpringConfiguration-servlet.xml

```
e<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

                <context:component-scan base-package="com.ordermanager.users.controller" />                     
                <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                                    <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
                                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean> 
                <mvc:annotation-driven/>
                <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/**"/>
```

Project Folder
[image]

i cant able access any css or JS file even after  controller and other function working fine ..
but if i open the following url in browser 
http://localhost:8080/OrderManager/resources/css/loginpagestyle.css, it's showing not 404 found.

Comment: From `Spring 3.1`, you can use - `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource mapping is wrong. Should be:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

After much search, my 404 issue was resolved by removing the initial "**/**" in the **location** setting value.  So instead of

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

as in the previous answer, I used:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"/>
```

Small change, but it did the trick. I'm assuming the "/" added an additional folder level to the path.  Also, I placed the **resources** folder directly under the **webapp** folder.

Thank you to [Suda's Tech Zone](http://sudarsan-techzone.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-include-external-css-file-in-jsp.html) for helping me with this issue.

Using Maven 4.0.0, eclispse kelper, java 1.7, mybatis 3.1.1.

Comment: why resources must go directly under webapp?
is there any way to customize its location?